# What is the keyboard Mac shortcut to find if a text is present in the android project in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

I am searching for text 'getSharedPreferences' and I see results of android jars, and not the Activity where I have this

```
  SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
```

Why is that? 
How to do the search properly in Android studio?

oh, I am using Mac

Comment: use ctl + h ...

Comment: You can specify a module / package using Ctrl + Shift + F

Comment: ctrl + shift + f ..... try this

Comment: Command == Ctrl, assuming you didn't remap your keys

Answer (score 2):

You can try cmd + H (for eclipse's key map and cmd + shift + F for default keymap), or look for Find in Path in your keymap.
You have options to find in the whole project or in specific directory

[image: Finding Text]

Comment: It minimizes Android studio. oh ok Eclipse key map. I am want to know Android Studio key map.

Comment: @user3705478 cmd + shift + f

Answer (score 1):

Just go to

> Edit > Find >Find In Path

Then Add text in edittext of Text to Find :

Comment: Keyboard shortcut please